# How can I create multiple web jobs under 1 Web App in azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops

I am trying to create a multible webjobs from 1 console application

I have 3 cities
'istanbul,ankara,izmir'
next year it will be
'istanbul,ankara,izmir,london,paris'
or more,

by using a loop  - ${{ each webJobName in split(variables.webJobNames, ',') }}:  a loop create webjobs in one WebApp but I am getting this error :

```
istanbul: /home/vsts/work/_temp/b6a20b2c-8714-4543-87d0-2cb52cbf142a.ps1:16
Line |
  16 |  $unzipPath = Join-Path /home/vsts/work/1/a "drop/$(istanbul)"
     |                                                     ~~~~~~
     | The term 'istanbul' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function,
     | script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
     | if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

azure-pipeline.yml :

```js
trigger:
  - main

variables:         
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  webJobNames: 'istanbul,ankara,izmir'
  webJobType: 'continuous'
  webJobFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  webJobCommand: ''
  webAppName: 'TestMessageBrokerListener'
  resourceGroupName : 'MyCompanyrsgtsteuw-app-eurotracs'
  subscription : 'MyCompany-SUB-TST-EUW-APP'
  location: 'weste'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Build stage'
  pool: 
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJustAJob
    displayName: 'Build Order Shipment Job'
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      displayName: 'checkout'
    
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
      displayName: "NuGet use 6.3.0"
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 6.3.0

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'nuget restore'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'select'

    - task: MSBuild@1
      displayName: 'msbuild'
      inputs:
        solution: 'src/MyCompany.Test.JustAJob/MyCompany.Test.JustAJob.csproj'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        msbuildArguments: '/p:OutputPath=$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyCompany.Test.JustAJob-$(Build.BuildNumber)/App_Data/jobs/continuous/MyCompany.Test.JustAJob'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'package'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyCompany.Test.JustAJob-$(Build.BuildNumber)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyCompany.Test.JustAJob-$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true
      
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'publish'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyCompany.Test.JustAJob-$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'

# Deploy web jobs to each location
- stage: Deploy_WebJobs
  displayName: 'Deploy stage'
  jobs:
    - job: DeployWebJobs
      displayName: 'Deploy Web Jobs'
      steps:
        - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
          displayName: 'Download artifact'
          inputs:
            buildType: 'current'
            downloadType: 'single'
            artifactName: 'drop'
            downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

        - ${{ each webJobName in split(variables.webJobNames, ',') }}:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: "Deploy ${{ webJobName }} Web Job"
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                echo ${{ webJobName }}
                echo $(webJobType)
                echo $(webJobFile)
                echo $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)
                
                Write-Host "Deploying ${{ webJobName }} Web Job"
                
                az login
                az account set --subscription $(subscription)
 
                
                # Unzip the web job artifact
                $artifactPath = Join-Path $(System.ArtifactsDirectory) "drop/MyCompany.Test.JustAJob-$(Build.BuildNumber).zip"
                $unzipPath = Join-Path $(System.ArtifactsDirectory) "drop/$(${{ webJobName }})"
                Expand-Archive -Path $artifactPath -DestinationPath $unzipPath -Force
                
                # Deploy the web job
                $webJobPath = Join-Path $unzipPath "App_Data/jobs/$(webJobType)/MyCompany.Test.JustAJob"
                az webapp deployment source config-zip --name $(webAppName) --resource-group $(resourceGroupName) --src $webJobPath
                # Add deployment steps specific to each web job here
```

Comment: `"drop/$(${{ webJobName }})"` should be `"drop/${{ webJobName }}"`.